# NSInternalInconsistencyException while loading custom view

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch

```
2011-12-01 10:30:37.211 basicViewBased[496:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "chapterViewController" nib but the view outlet was not set.'
2011-12-01 10:30:37.213 basicViewBased[496:207] Stack: (
    42182736,
    43340588,
    41920267,
    41920106,
    3534983,
    3526704,
    3526410,
    11676,
    3526533,
    3519391,
    3579886,
    3575616,
    3583801,
    3559329,
    3586719,
    3558971,
    11384,
    2903278,
    3400766,
    3410112,
    3404909,
    3030504,
    2922051,
    2953688,
    51175804,
    41461916,
    41457832,
    51169437,
    51169634,
    2945906,
    9732,
    9586
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

Comment: You should refer [Loaded nib but the view outlet was not set - new to InterfaceBuilder][1] and ['NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-\[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:\] loaded the GameView nib but the view outlet was not set][2] post.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763519/loaded-nib-but-the-view-outlet-was-not-set-new-to-interfacebuilder
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464010/nsinternalinconsistencyexception-reason-uiviewcontroller-loadviewfromnib

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the xib file you did not connect the view with xib.

Comment: we did that also but still it showing that exception

Comment: clean all targets and re run it

Comment: did that also. i m loading two custom view on one xib.