# loading non-existing .xib at run-time

Tags: xcode, exception, runtime, xib, nib

I created an IB file and linked it to MyAVController class.  But then I changed my mind and do all the layout programmatically in MyAVController class.  So I deleted the IB file (MyAVController.xib) from the project.  My project compiled successfully.  However when the program is launched, I got the following error:

'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "MyAVController" nib but the view outlet was not set.'

I saw a similar issue here
 ['NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the GameView nib but the view outlet was not set](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5464010/1299585)

but I think in my case, the application is looking to load MyAVController.xib at run-time which does not exist.  Am I missing something?  Thanks in advance for your comments.

-Utterly confused newbie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try searching your code "Edit/Find in workspace" for MyAVController - this should reveal where its attempting to load it.

Comment: thanks for your comment.  I deleted the executable on the device and that solved the exception problem