# How to debug "[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "SearchView" nib but the view outlet was not set" in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

Error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "SearchView" nib but the view outlet was not set.'

I tried everything to set the the view for "SearchView", but still crashing with signal abort message.

Comment: Check it out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464010/nsinternalinconsistencyexception-reason-uiviewcontroller-loadviewfromnib

Comment: In your SearchView check that all the elements have been connected via outlet

Comment: yes I checked....every element is  connected......

Answer (score 0):

Remove all outlets and reconnect again.

Comment: I removed all outlets and reconnected and checked as you said.....but crashing with signal abart..message.....

Comment: Is there any other way to overcome this issue......If you suggest that I would be very helpfull for me......

Comment: Make show name of nib and name that you are adding in viewcontroller both are same. Simply copy paste the name. Check nib name in file inspector in xcode.